# running a vbs file from java

Tags: java, vbscript, runtime

I have a VBS file test.vbs in `C:/work/selenium/chrome/` and I want to run it from my Java program, so I tried this but with no luck:

```
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
   Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
   try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "C:/work/selenium/chrome/test.vbs" );
   }
   catch( IOException e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

If I try to run some exe file with this method it runs well, but when I try to run a VBS file it says "not a valid win32 application".

Any idea how to run a VBS file from Java?

Comment: obviously in your case windows does not know how to execute this command. Please use the executor along with the script name: something like: cscript C:\\work\\selenium\\chrome\\test.vbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vbs-Script isn't natively executable like a bat, cmd or exe-Program. You have to start the interpreter (vbs.exe?) and hand your script over as a parameter:

```
String script = "C:\\work\\selenium\\chrome\\test.vbs";
// search for real path:
String executable = "C:\\windows\\...\\vbs.exe"; 
String cmdArr [] = {executable, script};
Runtime.getRuntime ().exec (cmdArr);
```

Answer (score 14):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "wscript D:/Send_Mail_updated.vbs" );
   }
   catch( IOException e ) {
      System.out.println(e);
      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

This is working fine where `Send_Mail_updated.vbs` is name of my VBS file

Answer (score 2):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cscript E:/Send_Mail_updated.vbs" )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
        "wscript.exe", "C:\\path\\example.vbs"
        });        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can use the code above to run vbs file.

Answer (score -1):

The complete code here

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
public class VBTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
             String line;
             OutputStream stdin = null;
             InputStream stderr = null;
             InputStream stdout = null;
             Process process =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cscript E:/Send_Mail_updated.vbs" );
             stdin = process.getOutputStream ();
             stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
             stdout = process.getInputStream ();

              // "write" the parms into stdin
              line = "param1" + "\n";
              stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
              stdin.flush();

              line = "param2" + "\n";
              stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
              stdin.flush();

              line = "param3" + "\n";
              stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
              stdin.flush();

              stdin.close();

              // clean up if any output in stdout
              BufferedReader brCleanUp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stdout));
              while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine ()) != null) {
                System.out.println ("[Stdout] " + line);
              }
              brCleanUp.close();

              // clean up if any output in stderr
              brCleanUp =
                new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stderr));
              while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine ()) != null) {
                System.out.println ("[Stderr] " + line);
              }
              brCleanUp.close();
           }
           catch( IOException e ) {
              System.out.println(e);
              //System.exit(0);
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code which reads the stdout and stderr is likely to deadlock.  To code this properly, you must use separate threads to read the output streams of the process