# run word macros without open word window

Tags: java, macros, struts2, ms-word, struts

i'm trying to execute msword macro from Java code using this:

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process process = rt.exec("WINWORD.EXE  <macroname> /w /m");
```

when this command executed the word open and close.
is there a way to run word macros in background without opening the msword window and close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that what you are asking is possible because you are sending a direct command to Process.

One way I would overcome this, is to create a `VBS` file one the file systems  (in this file I would create the MSWORD object, hide it and then send the macro command ).

And then [run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562139/running-a-vbs-file-from-java) the vbs file using java

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help:-

```
SET objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True 'This will Hide the Word Application
```

Comment: It is using VB Script

Answer (score 1):

This works, try it:

```
Dim Word

Dim WordDoc

Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Word.Visible = False

Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.open("D:\working_folder\abc.doc")

Word.Run "<macroname>"

WordDoc.Save

Word.Quit


Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set Word = Nothing
```